# Save the generated pdf directly to the server directory folder without user prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

A friend of mine gave me this task so I can learn advance programming a little bit easier. I am currently doing convertion of an html page to pdf using itext sharp and email the pdf as an attachement. My idea is to save the pdf first to the server machine in the folder name ToBeEmailedPDF folder before using it as an email attachment. The thing that bothers me is that this dialog as what you can see in the picture shows up using the code that I have below. [image]

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
pnlPDF.RenderControl(hw); // pnlPDF contains the html contents to be converted to pdf
string htmlDisplayText = sb.ToString();
Document document = new Document();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
StringReader se = new StringReader(htmlDisplayText);
HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
document.Open();
obj.Parse(se);
// step 5: we close the document
document.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I know many of you out there knows a better way or know how to solve my problem. Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is big difference between client-side and server-side.

`Response` class can output contents to client machine, if you need to save file on server use something like `File.WriteAllBytes` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)) method

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible for security reasons. Only the user can decide where he wants the attachment to be saved. Imagine if this was possible: you would then be able to save any kind of viruses into any kind of folders on the user's computer. As an alternative to showing the Save dialog you could open the PDF inline:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.pdf");
```

Comment: I am trying to save the file on the server side not on the client side. :) Thanks for your response. 1 vote for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save it using the following code:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(context.Server.MapPath("~") + "/PDF/" + reportName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```