# how to save pdf on server map path using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i am using following code for generate pdf and it is work perfect:

```
  string strQuery = "select * from userdata";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

        //Create a dummy GridView
        GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

it works good. but i am able to save this pdf to on server map path.

i have written below after pdfDoc.Close();

```
   String path  = Server.MapPath("~/mypdf.pdf");
```

But it is not saving pdf to server map path.

how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save the generated pdf directly to the server directory folder without user prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253989/save-the-generated-pdf-directly-to-the-server-directory-folder-without-user-prom)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are currently writing the document to the following output stream: `Response.OutputStream`

Once you do `pdfDoc.Close();`, the PDF bytes are gone.

If you want to save the PDF to the server, then you need to replace the following line:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
```

With this line:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(context.Server.MapPath("~") + "mypdf.pdf");
```

Now your bytes won't be sent to the browser, but the PDF will be created on your server.

Comment: This shows error - PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(path);
it shows error on `New Filestream`.

Comment: yes i solved already with this code :  `PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));`

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie do you how to do it using `XMLWorkerHelper`